# congruence with exponential, $ 8^{2012} + 2012^8 $

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have an assignment where the following statement is:

Determine the lowest positive integer that is congruent with the statement mod 12:
$$ 8^{2012} + 2012^8 $$

How can I solve this? I have totally forgotten...

Comment: Compute mod $4$ (instant) and mod $3$.

Comment: why does that work?

Comment: There are many possible strategies. But in this case, factoring $12$ is useful, since we can do calculations mod $4$ and mod $3$ with minimal calculation.

Comment: we get $$8^{2012}+2012^{8}\equiv 8 \mod 12$$

Comment: @theva: You can use that $4^n\equiv 4\pmod{12}$ for every positive integer $n$ if you can prove that.

Comment: prove it by induction for example.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\;8^n\equiv\begin{cases}4\mod12&\text{if $n$ is even},\\8\mod12&\text{if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}.$

Furthermore $\;2012\equiv 8\mod 12$, hence
$$8^{2012}+2012^8\equiv 4+4=8\mod 12.$$